# What does the Cross Product of two vectors actually mean?

Tags: vectors, geometry

I was just going through a torque lecture video provided by professor. And all of a sudden the thing cross-product really struck me. Professor just put it as Vector $\vec A$ cross  Vector $\vec B$ and it results as a vector which is perpendicular to plane containing two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$. Is this new vector which we get as a result of cross-product represents an abstract quantity like twisting tendency in torque.

It just seems like I am asked to know this as a declarative matter of fact.

But, I am not getting it in terms of Vector multiplication which implies as a product or multiplying of two vectors.
In Math, we had a simple meaning like $4$ times $2$  are 8 as $(2+2+2+2)$ and $2$ times $4$ as $(4+4)$. But why is this concept of the vector product is not clarified in this way in the textbook?
It making me really confusing although I feel like I have understood this concept.

Comment: I guess it's hard to know exactly what you're asking. But one view on the cross product is... this "operation" on two vectors is noticed to describe reality. That's why we use it. Whether one should call it multiplication is up to you - but either way it is important for physics. There are parallels with multiplication of real numbers but it's obviously not the same thing. It just is what it is and it turns out that you can describe reality like that.

Comment: What do you mean by “your torque lecture video”? There are no lecture videos on this site. Did some question or answer that you read link to one?

Comment: Can you clarify, as it is difficult to understand what the question is. Yes, torque can be represented using a cross product.

Answer (score 1):

> But why is this concept of the vector product is not clarified in this way in the textbook?

because it cannot be represented as repeated addition like elementary multiplication.

*Vector multiplication is not regular multiplication*.

Just like 1.5*2.1.  See? You cannot represent this as repeated addition.
So, a*b = b+b+b....a times is true only for positive integers

Consider negative numbers zero or worse complex number multiplication. These are *expanded* type of multiplications. They are not your basic multiplication

So is the case of vector product(dot or cross). Just because they are **termed** as product this does not mean they are same operation as multipliction of positive integers.

**They are completely different**

Also this terminology is due to Gibbs

> The cross notation and the name "cross product" began with Gibbs. Originally they appeared in privately published notes for his students in 1881 as Elements of Vector Analysis.

Source: Wikipedia(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

They used it probably taking in mind some similarities

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about the scalar product is that if you have vectors $\vec A=(A_x,A_y,A_z)$ and $\vec B=(B_x,B_y,B_z)$ then you can write the product $\vec A . \vec B=A_xB_x+A_y B_y+A_z B_z$.  This is a number. It is a *scalar*, in that if you rotate the axes its value does not change. You can show that with a bit of maths or you can take it as obvious.

You can also write the cartesian product $\vec A \otimes \vec B=\left( \matrix{A_xB_x & A_xB_y & A_x B_z\\A_y B_x & A_y B_y & A_y B_z\\A_z B_x &A_z B_y& A_z B_z  } \right) $. This is a 3 by 3 matrix. It is actually a *tensor* in tht if you rotate the axes it transforms in a specific way.

You can also take the cartesian product the other way round.  $\vec B \otimes \vec A=\left( \matrix{A_xB_x & A_yB_x & A_z B_x\\A_x B_y & A_y B_y & A_z B_y\\A_x B_z &A_y B_z& A_z B_z  } \right) $ which is not quite the same - look at the off-diagonal elements. And you can take the difference of the two:

$\vec A \otimes \vec B - \vec B \otimes \vec A=\left( \matrix{0 & A_xB_y-A_yB_x & A_x B_z-A_z B_x\\A_yB_x-A_x B_y & 0 & A_yB_z-A_z B_y\\A_zB_x-A_x B_z &A_zB_y-A_y B_z& 0  } \right) $

This 3 by 3 matrix has 9 elements but as it is antisymmetric there are only 3 independent ones, as the diagonal ones are zero and the off-diagonal ones are the same apart from the sign.

These 3 quantities can be put into a vector with 3 components: the $xy$ terms go to make the $z$ component, the $xz$ terms in $y$ and the $yz$ terms in $x$. $\left( \matrix{A_yB_z-B_yA_z\\A_zB_x-A_xB_z\\A_xB_y-A_yB_x}\right)$. Which is the co=ordinate form of the vector product, equivalent to $AB\sin\theta$ in a perpendicular direction.

So that's the vector product: take the difference between the two possible cartesian products, and pull out the 3 components.

(It's interesting how this only works in 3 dimensions. In 2D there is just one off-diagonal element. In 4D there are 6. (so-called 6-vectors do appear in relativistic electrodynamics). Only in 3D does the `vector product' prescription give a vector with the right number of elements.)

To be a bit more explicit, mathematically (switching from $xyz$ to $123$ notation for the axes) one uses the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ which is zero if any of the $ijk$ are the same, $+1$ for even permutations $123,231, 312$ and -1 for odd permutations $132,213, 321$.

$(\vec A \times \vec B)_i=   \sum_j \sum_k \epsilon_{ijk} A_j B_k$